# Tesseract spaces and numbers

Tags: tesseract

I'm using Tesseract on some images (excellent quality computer-generated 300 dpi) and generally it is working ok. But there's a problem with the numbers in that 1123.45 is being returned as 1 123.45. It seems it's being a little aggressive on the numeric kerning and breaking things where it shouldn't. I've dug through the big list of parameters and tried tweaking a few but not had success. Any recommendations?

Thanks
Terry

Comment: Did you ever find an answer for this?  I am having the same problem, with both "I" and "1" numbers in fixed fonts being recognized with extra spaces, so that (for example) "MISSISSIPPI" would get recognized as "M I SS I SS I PP I"

Comment: I gave up in the end, the output was generally too unstable for me to rely on and I needed it to be much better.